# How to duplicate rows in a feature matrix array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following feature matrix X (ie. with 4 rows and 3 features):

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

(array([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]),
```

How do I duplicate say, the 1st and 2nd row twice, the 3rd row 3 times and no duplication in the 4th row, ie. I want to get this:

```
(array([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  2,  3]
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 4,  5,  6]
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [ 7,  8,  9]
        [ 7,  8,  9]
        [10, 11, 12]]),
```

Is there a way for me to multiply the features matrix X with an array of weights, say something like this:

```
np.array([2,2,3,1])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into `np.repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through indexing:

```
repeats = np.array([2,2,3,1])
indices = np.repeat(range(len(X)), repeats)
X[indices]
```

Where indices is

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.repeat(X, [2, 2, 3, 1], axis=0)
```

Comment: please provide some narrative.

Comment: Check out the official Numpy documentation. I believe this will help you out. https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Comment: I mean - in your answer - add a narrative to explain rather than just code.